# ReactJS How to get first option of <select> on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch a data atribute of the default option from a select list.

I have this:

```
<select className="form-control" id="select" onChange={(e) => state.selectedOptionValue(e)} value={state.selectedOption}>
   {data.map((option, i) => <Options key={i} option={option}/>)}
</select>

const Options = observer(({ state, option }) => (
  <option data-option-id={option.id} value={option.displayText}>
    {option.displayText}
  </option>
))
```

then in my state file I have the `onChange` handler:

```
async selectedOptionValue (e) {
   this.selectedOption = e.target.value
   this.optionId = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-option-id');
}
```

this works fine so far, but I need to set `this.optionId` by default, so I have to fetch the first option's `data-options-id` on render

How can I do that?